# convert bitmap from 16bpp to 8bpp in objective c

Tags: objective-c, bitmap, pixel

I need to convert 16bpp greyscale bitmap data into 8bpp. My image file format is not supported by mac os x so i subclassed NSBitmapImageRep. I've implemented the method `imageRepWithData:`

```
+ (id)imageRepWithData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"imageRepWithData called");
    if (data.length < 2) return nil;
    NSString *magicNumberP5 = @"P5";
    const unsigned char *mnP5 = (const unsigned char *)[magicNumberP5 UTF8String];
    unsigned char headerBuffer[2];
    [data getBytes:headerBuffer length:2];

    if (memcmp(mnP5, headerBuffer, 2) != 0) {
        NSLog(@"It is not supported pgm file format.");
        return nil;
    }

    NSArray *pgmParameters = [self extractPgmHeader:data];

    // width in pixels
    NSInteger width = [[pgmParameters objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
    // height in pixels
    NSInteger height = [[pgmParameters objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
    // imageData contains bytes of Bitmap only. Without header
    NSData *imageData = [pgmParameters objectAtIndex:3];
    // Number of bytes in bitmap (length)
    NSUInteger imageLength = [imageData length];

    // calculate number bytes per component
    size_t bytesPerCompontent = imageLength / (width * height) * 8;
    // calculate number of bytes per pixel
    size_t bytesPerPixel = bytesPerCompontent;
    // calculate number of bytes per row
    size_t bytesPerRow = width * (imageLength / (width * height));

    // tmp test
    NSData *eightBitBitmapData = [RWTPGMRep convert16BppTo8BppFromBitmapData:imageData];
    // end of tmp test

    CGDataProviderRef provider =
    CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)CFBridgingRetain(imageData));

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericGrayGamma2_2);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width,
                                        height,
                                        bytesPerCompontent,
                                        bytesPerPixel,
                                        bytesPerRow,
                                        colorSpace,
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        false,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    if (imageRef == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"CGImageCreate() failed!");
    }
    RWTPGMRep *imageRep = [[RWTPGMRep alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
    if (imageRep == nil) {
        NSLog(@"imageRep is NULL");
    }
    return imageRep;
}
```

So I can display this image wchich pixels are coded by 2 bytes...

But I need to convert this image to 8bpp For this purpose I wrote a method `convert16BppTo8BppFromBitmapData:`

```
+ (NSData *)convert16BppTo8BppFromBitmapData:(NSData *)sixteenBitBitmapData
{    
    // number of pixels
    NSUInteger size = [sixteenBitBitmapData length] / sizeof(UInt16);

    // allocate memory for 16bpp array
    UInt16 *array16 = malloc(size * sizeof(UInt16));
    UInt16 *array16Ptr = array16;
    // get bytes to array16
    [sixteenBitBitmapData getBytes:array16
                            length:(size * sizeof(UInt16))];

    // allocate memory for 8bpp array (converted values of pixels)
    UInt8 *array8 = malloc(size * sizeof(UInt8));
    UInt8 *array8Ptr = array8;

    // convert 16bpp values to 8bpp values
    NSUInteger i = size;
    while (i--) {
        *array8Ptr++ = (UInt8)((*array16Ptr++) >> 8);
    }

    // pack an array8 into NSData object
    NSData *eightBitBitmapData = [NSData dataWithBytes:array8
                                                length:size];    
    return eightBitBitmapData;
}
```

I have checked that method and it seems to work corectly... Only for test purpose I've modified my `imageRepWithData:` method to create imageRef with 8bpp and display converted image... Here is my changes:

```
// tmp test
NSData *eightBitBitmapData = [RWTPGMRep convert16BppTo8BppFromBitmapData:imageData];
size_t bytesPerCompontent8 = eightBitBitmapData.length / (width * height) * 8;
size_t bytesPerPixel8 = bytesPerCompontent8;
size_t bytesPerRow8 = (width * (eightBitBitmapData.length / (width * height)));


CGDataProviderRef provider =
CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)CFBridgingRetain(eightBitBitmapData));

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericGrayGamma2_2);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width,
                                    height,
                                    bytesPerCompontent8,
                                    bytesPerPixel8,
                                    bytesPerRow8,
                                    colorSpace,
                                    kCGImageAlphaNone,
                                    provider,
                                    NULL,
                                    false,
                                    kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
// end of tmp test
```

But the result is not as I expected...
The image with 16bpp which I am displaying looks like:
http://i40.tinypic.com/2isa9tx.png

and my image converted to 8bb bitmap looks like:
http://i39.tinypic.com/as8c3.png

Do you have an idea what's wrong? I would be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: But the converted image looks more interesting :-)

Comment: Remark: Your variable names are misleading, e.g. bytesPerPixel8 contains *bits* per pixel.

Comment: You have right. I will fix it, but it is not the case :/